# Prove: $(\det(A-B)+\det(A+B) )^2 \ge 4\det(A^2-B^2 )$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Let $A,B \in  \mathcal{M}_n (\mathbb{R})$ two matrices so that:
>
> a) $AB^2=B^2 A$ and $BA^2=A^2 B$
>
> b) $\text{rank}(AB-BA)=1$.
>
> Prove: $$(\det(A-B)+\det(A+B) )^2≥4\det(A^2-B^2 )$$

---

This is a solution:

> Denote $C=AB-BA$. Then $rank(C)=1$ so $C=p\cdot q^T$ where $p,q$ are
>   column vectors and $tr(C)=0$. This proves that 
>   $C^2=p\cdot q^T\cdot p\cdot q^T=tr(C)C=0.$
>
> If $D=A^2-B^2$ then a) implies that $CD=DC$ and $D$ commutes with
>   $A,B$.

***As a consequence $tr(CD^{-1})=0$.***

> If $\det(D)=0$ we have nothing to prove. Else $D$ is invertible and
>   $(CD^{-1})^2=0$.
>
> We have $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2+AB-BA=D+C$. We would like to prove that
>   $\det(A-B)(B-A)=\det(A^2-B^2)$.
>
> For this define $ f(t)=\det(AB-BA+t(A^2-B^2))$
>
> and see that $f(t)=\det(D)\det(CD^{-1}+tI)=\det(A^2-B^2)\cdot t^n$.
>
> Replace $t=1$ in the previous relation to get 
>   $\det(AB-BA+A^2-B^2)=\det(A^2-B^2)$ and we are done.

But i don't understand why  $tr(CD^{-1})=0$ ??

Answer (score 1):

Because $(CD^{-1})^2=0$, then $CD^{-1}$ only has zero eigenvalue.
There should be a mistake in the order of proof.

Comment: The "As a consequence" part should come after the discussion of whether $D$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Note $D^{-1}$ also commutes with $C$, so

$CD^{-1}CD^{-1}=C^2D^{-1}D^{-1}=0$

Let $\lambda_i$ be any eigenvalue of $CD^{-1}$. Then $\lambda_i^2$ is eigenvalue of $(CD^{-1})^2$. So $\lambda_i^2=0$ and $\lambda_i=0$.

Thus $Tr(CD^{-1})=\sum \limits_{k=1}^n\lambda_k=0$.